# Grommet: TypeError: Cannot read property 'modelSchemas' of undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, grommet

I'm using grommet version 1.3.4 and trying to use mongodb with node js and express. When I run `npm install` I get the following TypeError:

```
/home/jorge/Desktop/crud-app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:373
  if (!this.modelSchemas[name]) {
            ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'modelSchemas' of undefined
    at Mongoose.model (/home/jorge/Desktop/crud-app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:373:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/jorge/Desktop/crud-app/dist-server/models/person.model.js:18:39)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:702:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:713:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:543:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:650:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/jorge/Desktop/crud-app/dist-server/controllers/person.controller.js:9:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:702:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:713:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:543:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:650:17)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

This is the code I used for the Person schema:

```
import { Schema, model } from 'mongoose';

const PersonSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    lastName: String,
    age: Number,
    gender: String,
    updatedAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    status: Boolean,
});

export default model('Person', PersonSchema);
```

And babel transpiled it into this:

```
'use strict';

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
    value: true
});

var _mongoose = require('mongoose');

var PersonSchema = new _mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    lastName: String,
    age: Number,
    gender: String,
    updatedAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    status: Boolean
});

exports.default = (0, _mongoose.model)('Person', PersonSchema);
//# sourceMappingURL=person.model.js.map
```

Apparently it is failing at the last line where I export the model. I'm not very familiar with either mongodb and grommet, so any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 11):

apparently `import { Schema, model } from 'mongoose';` doesn't work... I had to use this instead:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const PersonSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    lastName: String,
    age: Number,
    gender: String,
    updatedAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    status: Boolean,
});

export default mongoose.model('Person', PersonSchema);
```